# Connect to SQL Server in web.config (ASP.NET MVC) using Windows authentication not working, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

It is under configsection but it's not working and it didn't connect to SQL Server. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Of course, my data source name is `.` not other thing.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompanyContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Learning_EFCF;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What is the Error?

Comment: What @Nikolaus wrote, plus - try with `Integrated Security = true` is should work both ways from what I read, but in practice using `true` is much more common than `SSPI` maybe there are some differences after all.